# Virtual keyword makes inaccessible a method from the derived objects

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Super{
public:
    virtual void showName();
};

class Special1 : public Super {
public:
    void showName();
    void sayHello();
};

class Special2 : public Super {
public:
    void showName();
    void sayGoodbye();
};

void Super::showName() {
    std::cout << "I'm super!" << std::endl;
}

void Special1::showName() {
    std::cout << "I'm special1" << std::endl;
}

void Special1::sayHello() {
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}

void Special2::showName() {
    std::cout << "I'm special2" << std::endl;
}

void Special2::sayGoodbye() {
    std::cout << "Goodbye" << std::endl;
}

int main () {
    Super *oSpec=new Super;

    Special1 *o1=static_cast<Special1 *>(oSpec);
    Special2 *o2=static_cast<Special2 *>(oSpec);

    oSpec->showName();
    o1->showName();
    o2->showName();

    o1->sayHello();
    o2->sayGoodbye();

    delete oSpec;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, it shows this output:

```
I'm super!
I'm super!
I'm super!
Hello
Goodbye
```

But, if I remove the `virtual` keyword from the declaration of the `Super` class:

```
class Super{
public:
    /*virtual*/ void showName();
};
```

The output becomes the correct one:

```
I'm super!
I'm special1
I'm special2
Hello
Goodbye
```

Then, my question is, why the presence of the `virtual` keyword makes the pointers `o1` and `o2` run the method `Super::showName()` instead of `Special1::showName()` or `Special2::showName()`?

Comment: Using static_cast<> above is undefined behavior. The code is broken and only works at the whim of your compiler and its current flags.

Comment: The code causes Undefined Behavior, you cannot cast a `Super*` to a `Special# *` object unless the pointed object is actually a `Special#` instance, which in your case it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is closer to correct with `virtual` and incorrect with it (unless you really wanted that). The cast doesn't change the type of the objects, just the type of the pointers. They are still of type `Super`, and so it's `Super::showName` that should run.

Casting one pointer type to another pointer type doesn't change the type of the thing pointed to. How could it? The whole point of virtual functions is to be able to call methods on 'generic' pointers and get the correct derived class method.

The classic example of why you use virtual functions is for musicians. You might have a function that causes the entire orchestra to play by calling the `Play` method on every `Musician *` it gets passed. For a `Pianist`, that has to call `Pianist::Play`.

Normally, the compiler figures out which function to call at compile time -- early binding. The only information the compiler is sure to know is the type of the pointer. The `virtual` keyword causes the binding to occur late, at run time, when the actual type of the class member is known.

By the way, you can still call the base class method, by using a scope override. For example `o1->Super::showName();`.

In fact, the result you claim is 'correct' is catastrophic. Running `Special1::showName()` with the `this` pointer pointing to an object that is not of type `Special1` (or something derived from it) is undefined behavior and can easily lead to a crash.

Comment: You can't really say that either output is "correct", since the program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: You are correct. You cannot access a class member through a pointer to a type the class member is not an instance of. (I added that to my answer. Thanks.)

Comment: I really dislike your use of the term 'correct' above. There is no correct behavior for undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Because your code in `main` is wrong.  The objects all say "I'm super" because for them (in reality, in the background), the *most derived type* is still `super`.  That's what they were created as.

Your static cast breaks all the rules, to be undefined behavior (anything can happen), because you tell the compiler that `o1` is a `Special1`, when in fact, it is *not* a type of `Special1`.

`virtual` functions are usually useful when you create a bunch of *derived* objects, and store them in a pointer/container that holds pointers to the *base* object.  Not the other way around.  You want to create pointers of type `Special1` and `Special2` and store them in pointers to `super`.

Answer (score 2):

Your cast (`Special1 *o1=static_cast<Special1 *>(oSpec);`) is undefined behavior in both cases, so any output at all is acceptable as far as the language is concerned. You've taken an object of type `Super` and lied to the compiler, telling it that it's really a derived class. In this case, what happens is that you still get the result of the parent class `Super` that it really is.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is just undefined.
Trying to reason why it works in a particular way is useless.

Here:

```
Super *oSpec=new Super;
```

oSpec points at an object  of `type` Super.

Thus in these statements. The casts have undefined behavior, as the object pointed at by oSpec is neither a Special 1 or a Special 2).

```
Special1 *o1=static_cast<Special1 *>(oSpec);
Special2 *o2=static_cast<Special2 *>(oSpec);
```

If you use dynamica_cast<> (like you should when casting up the class hierarchy). You will find the result are NULL.

```
Special1 *o1=dynamic_cast<Special1 *>(oSpec);
Special2 *o2=dynamic_cast<Special2 *>(oSpec);

std::cout << "O1(" << (void*)o1 << ") O2(" << (void*)o2 << ")\n";
```

This will show that both pointers are NULL.